# Retrieve nth cdr of a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to return the nth cdr of a list. For example, I say
`(nth-cdr 3 '(a b c d e))` and i would get `(c d e)` as output. I am not sure where I am going wrong with my code.

My approach is this. I will check if `(= num 0)` if it is, I will return the list. If not, I will recursively call `nth-cdr` and subtract 1 from `num` and `cdr list`

The code is this

```
(define arbitrary-cdr (lambda (num list)
                        (if (= num 0)
                            '()
                            (arbitrary-cdr (- num 1) (cdr list))
                            )))
```

However, I get this error when i try doing `(arbitrary-cdr 3 ‘(a b c d e))`

```
‘: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

I am not sure what this means. When I say that, it means I hit the base case and would just like to return the list. I think my logic is correct though.

Comment: In `(arbitrary-cdr 3 ‘(a b c d e))`, you have written a "curly" quote character  (an actual quote character) instead of a "straight" one. It's not a syntax error because it's a valid identifier in Scheme.

Comment: Please don't replace your question with a new question after you've got an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code that you posted was:

```
(define arbitrary-cdr
  (lambda (num list)
    (if (= num 0)
        (list)
        (arbitrary-cdr (- num 1) (cdr list)))))
```

The error that you received was:

```
scratch.rkt> (arbitrary-cdr 3 '(a b d c e))
; application: not a procedure;
;  expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
;   given: '(c e)
```

The problem was that you used `list` as an argument to the `arbitrary-cdr` procedure; since Racket is a lisp-1, procedures do not have their own namespace, so this redefined `list`. With `(list)`, and with `list` redefined the code attempted to call `((c e))`, but `(c e)` is not a procedure.

This is a great example for why you should *not* use `list` or other built-in procedure identifiers as parameters in your own procedure definitions in Scheme or Racket. You can get away with this in Common Lisp, because Common Lisp is a lisp-2, i.e., has a separate namespace for functions.

With your updated code:

```
(define arbitrary-cdr
  (lambda (num list)
    (if (= num 0)
        '()
        (arbitrary-cdr (- num 1) (cdr list)))))
```

I don't get the error you report; maybe your code is not quite what you have posted. But, there is a mistake in the logic of your code. As it is, an empty list will always be returned:

```
scratch.rkt> (arbitrary-cdr 3 '(a b c d e f))
'()
```

The problem is that when the base case is reached you should return the input list, not an empty list. That is, given `(arbitrary-cdr 0 '(a b c))`, you want the result to be `(a b c)`. This also means that your test case is wrong; `(arbitrary-cdr 0 '(a b c d e))` --> `'(a b c d e)`, and `(arbitrary-cdr 3 '(a b c d e))` --> `'(d e)`.

Here is your code rewritten, using `xs` instead of `list` to avoid the redefinition, and returning `xs` instead of an empty list when the base case is reached:

```
(define arbitrary-cdr
  (lambda (num xs)
    (if (= num 0)
        xs
        (arbitrary-cdr (- num 1) (cdr xs)))))
```

Sample interactions:

```
scratch.rkt> (arbitrary-cdr 0 '(a b c d e))
'(a b c d e)
scratch.rkt> (arbitrary-cdr 1 '(a b c d e))
'(b c d e)
scratch.rkt> (arbitrary-cdr 3 '(a b c d e))
'(d e)
```